# Java: PostgreSQL Hibernate ERROR: INSERT has more expressions than target columns

Tags: java, sql, database, postgresql, hibernate

The error "INSERT has more expressions than target columns" occurs during a transaction commit command in Hibernate. The code is given below where the error is thrown during the execution of transaction.commit() command:

```
@Override
public void saveHearingDetails(HearingDetails hearingDetails)
        throws Exception {
    Session session = SessionFactoryUtils
            .doGetSession(sessionFactory, true);
    System.out.println(session);
    Transaction transaction = null;
    try {
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        session.saveOrUpdate(hearingDetails);
        transaction.commit();
        session.flush();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        throw new Exception(ex);
    } finally {
        SessionFactoryUtils.releaseSession(session, sessionFactory);
    }
  }
```

The stack trace is as follows:

```html
DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-9] SQL.logStatement(111) | 
    insert 
    into
        public.hearingdetails
        (gist_of_hearing, heaing_dt, heaing_dt_with_timestamp, process_updated_date, case_complete, status, fileno1, fileno2, fileno3, hearing_no, dist_code, revdiv_code) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-9] StringType.nullSafeSet(151) | binding 'Gist Of Hearing' to parameter: 1
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-9] TimestampType.nullSafeSet(151) | binding '2023-12-29 00:00:00' to parameter: 2
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-9] TimestampType.nullSafeSet(151) | binding '2023-12-29 13:00:07' to parameter: 3
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-9] TimestampType.nullSafeSet(151) | binding '2023-12-29 13:00:07' to parameter: 4
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-9] CharacterType.nullSafeSet(144) | binding null to parameter: 5
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-9] StringType.nullSafeSet(151) | binding 'P' to parameter: 6
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-9] StringType.nullSafeSet(151) | binding '5090' to parameter: 7
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-9] StringType.nullSafeSet(151) | binding 'B3' to parameter: 8
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-9] StringType.nullSafeSet(151) | binding '2018' to parameter: 9
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-9] IntegerType.nullSafeSet(151) | binding '3' to parameter: 10
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-9] StringType.nullSafeSet(151) | binding '16' to parameter: 11
TRACE [http-nio-8080-exec-9] StringType.nullSafeSet(151) | binding '91' to parameter: 12
WARN [http-nio-8080-exec-9] JDBCExceptionReporter.logExceptions(100) | SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42601
ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-9] JDBCExceptionReporter.logExceptions(101) | ERROR: INSERT has more expressions than target columns
  Where: PL/pgSQL function hearing_history() line 11 at SQL statement
ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-9] AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(324) | Could not synchronize database state with session
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not insert: [com.nic.edistrict.model.HearingDetails]
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2295)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2688)
    at org.hibernate.action.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:79)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:279)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:263)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:50)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1027)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:365)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:137)
    at com.nic.edistrict.dao.impl.PattaTransferDaoImpl.saveHearingDetails(PattaTransferDaoImpl.java:437)
    at com.nic.edistrict.services.impl.PattaInformationManagerImpl.saveHearingDetails(PattaInformationManagerImpl.java:50)
    at com.nic.edistrict.action.state.PattainformationAction.upnextHeraingDt(PattainformationAction.java:940)
```

But the number of values in the command is same as the number of target columns as it can be seen in the "insert into public.hearingdetails (gist_of_hearing, heaing_dt, heaing_dt_with_timestamp, process_updated_date, case_complete, status, fileno1, fileno2, fileno3, hearing_no, dist_code, revdiv_code) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)" command shown in logs by Hibernate (12 values are inserted into 12 target columns).

What could be issue here? Kindly suggest solutions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is actually giving you more information:

> ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-9] JDBCExceptionReporter.logExceptions(101) | ERROR: INSERT has more expressions than target columns
>
> **Where: PL/pgSQL function hearing_history() line 11 at SQL statement**

Look's like you have some triggers or procedures attached to the insertion in this table and this procedure is not valid.

Comment: Number of values in the command is same as the number of target columns as it can be seen in the insert command. But I'll also check any possible triggers or procedures attached to the insertion in the table. Thank you for the answer, anyway.

Comment: The error says it: you have a function `hearing_history()` somewhere